# Simplify try/except with more than one except

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

I have try/except block which handles API requests to some client.

```
 while attempts < 10:
    try: 
        r = requests.post(server, data=contents,
                          auth=HTTPBasicAuth(service_userid, service_pswd))
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print ('Http Error:',errh)
        attempts += 1  
        if attempts == 10: 
            body = 'Http Error: ' + str(errh)
            subject = 'Failure'
            sendEmailMessage(SMPTHOST, fromEmailAddr, toEmailAddr, subject, body)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ('Error Connecting:',errc)
        attempts += 1  
        if attempts == 10: 
            body = 'Error Connecting: ' + str(errh)
            subject = 'Failure'
            sendEmailMessage(SMPTHOST, fromEmailAddr, toEmailAddr, subject, body)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print ('Timeout Error:',errt)
        attempts += 1  
        if attempts == 10: 
            body = 'Timeout Error: ' + str(errh)
            subject = 'Failure'
            sendEmailMessage(SMPTHOST, fromEmailAddr, toEmailAddr, subject, body)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print ('Unidentified error: ',err)
        attempts += 1  
        if attempts == 10: 
            body = 'Unidentified error: ' + str(errh)
            subject = 'Failure'
            sendEmailMessage(SMPTHOST, fromEmailAddr, toEmailAddr, subject, body)
```

How can I simplify above code? 
In general, I would like to handle HTTP response error codes. I want to send an e-mail with specific error information only in case I get at least 10 error codes for the same call.

Comment: Use a function with parameters for the values that change between excepts.

Comment: yes, I can do this, but still I will have usage of the same function in each except and also if statement will be in each except clause.

Comment: No, the if statement will be *within* the function. The except block will consist of a single line, to call the function.

Comment: yeah, you are right, but still this is checking in each except. I was thinking about using something like: when while loop will reach specified value (in this case 10), send a message with current error information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the action to perform is the same in each case, just group the exceptions into a single one, then customize the messages according to the error class / class name:

```
    except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError,requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,requests.exceptions.RequestException,requests.exceptions.Timeout) as err:
        error_message = "{}: ".format(err.__class__.__name__,err)
        print (error_message)
        attempts += 1  
        if attempts == 10: 
            body = error_message
            subject = 'Failure'
            sendEmailMessage(SMPTHOST, fromEmailAddr, toEmailAddr, subject, body)
```

If you need an indirection, just create a dictionary class name => string/action to perform/whatever.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-François Fabre. This is what I wanted to do :)

Comment: I have one additional question here. As I want to send a message only when while loop will reach specified value, is there a way to use it somehow instead of checking each time if attempts variable == 10?